# Bind9 and MySQL DLZ Buffer Error

Tags: mysql, bind, named

I compiled Bind 9 from source (see below) and set up Bind9 with MySQL DLZ.
I keep getting an error when I attempt to fetch anything from the server about buffer overflow. I've googled many times but can not find anything on how to fix this error.

**Configure options:**

> root@anacrusis:/opt/bind9/bind-9.9.1-P3# named -V BIND 9.9.1-P3 built
>   with '--prefix=/opt/bind9' '--mandir=/opt/bind9/man'
>   '--infodir=/opt/bind9/info' '--sysconfdir=/opt/bind9/config'
>   '--localstatedir=/opt/bind9/var' '--enable-threads'
>   '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared'
>   '--enable-static' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr'
>   '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-dlz-postgres=no' '--with-dlz-mysql=yes'
>   '--with-dlz-bdb=no' '--with-dlz-filesystem=yes' '--with-dlz-stub=yes'
>   '--with-dlz-ldap=yes' '--enable-ipv6' 'CFLAGS=-fno-strict-aliasing
>   -DDIG_SIGCHASE -O2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions' 'CPPFLAGS=' using OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012 using libxml2
>   version: 2.7.8

This is the error I get when I `dig example.com` (with debug):

> Query String: select ttl, type, mx_priority, case when
>   lower(type)='txt' then concat('"', data, '"')
>           else data end from dns_records where zone = 'example.com' and host = '@'
>
> 17-Sep-2012 01:09:33.610 dns_rdata_fromtext: buffer-0x7f5bfca73360:1:
>   unexpected end of input 17-Sep-2012 01:09:33.610 dns_sdlz_putrr
>   returned error. Error code was: unexpected end of input 17-Sep-2012
>   01:09:33.610 Query String: select ttl, type, mx_priority, case when
>   lower(type)='txt' then concat('"', data, '"')
>           else data end from dns_records where zone = 'example.com' and host = '*'
>
> 17-Sep-2012 01:09:33.610 query.c:2579: fatal error: 17-Sep-2012
>   01:09:33.610 RUNTIME_CHECK(result == 0) failed 17-Sep-2012
>   01:09:33.610 exiting (due to fatal error in library)

**Named.conf**

```
options {
    directory "/opt/bind9/";
    allow-query-cache { none; };
    allow-query { any; };
    recursion no;
};

dlz "Mysql zone" {
    database "mysql
    {host=localhost dbname=system ssl=false user=root pass=*password*}
    {select zone from dns_records where zone = '$zone$'}
    {select ttl, type, mx_priority, case when lower(type)='txt' then concat('\"', data, '\"')
        else data end from dns_records where zone = '$zone$' and host = '$record$'}
    {}
    {}
    {}
    {}";
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you run named single-threaded (with "-n 1" parameter)? If not, named will crash in various places when working on more than one query in parallel, since the MySQL DLZ module is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Manually log into the DB and run the query. See what it comes up with. The error says it's got an unexpected end of input, meaning it was expecting to get something and it never got it. So the first thing is to see if it you can get it manually. Maybe the `mysqld` isn't running. Maybe the user isn't defined or password is set wrong or permissions are not granted on that table. These could all account for the error.

Assuming all this works then you have two options:

- Enable more logging in your `named.conf` so you have more data to work with on what's happening
- Remove and reinstall `BIND`, ensuring that all hashes match on all libraries and that all dependancies are in place.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten Bind with DLZ working on CentOS 7. I do not get the error that is effecting you.

I realize this is an older post but I thought I would share my conf files , and configure options.

I am using Bind 9.11.0

configure

```
 ./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc/bind --localstatedir=/var --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-threads --enable-largefile --with-libtool --enable-shared --enable-static --with-openssl=/usr --with-gssapi=/usr --with-gnu-ld --with-dlz-postgres=no --with-dlz-mysql=yes --with-dlz-bdb=no --with-dlz-filesystem=yes --with-dlz-stub=yes --enable-ipv6
```

named.conf

```
// This is the primary configuration file for the BIND DNS server named.
//
// Please read /usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz for information on the
// structure of BIND configuration files in Debian, *BEFORE* you customize
// this configuration file.
//
// If you are just adding zones, please do that in /etc/bind/named.conf.local
#auskommentiert !!!
#include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
#include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
#include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";


key "rndc-key" {
            // how was key encoded
            algorithm hmac-md5;
            // what is the pass-phrase for the key
                secret "noway";
             };


#options {
#default-key "rndc-key";
#default-server 127.0.0.1;
#default-port 953;
#};

controls {
inet * port 953 allow { any; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
#inet * port 53 allow { any; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};



logging {
    channel query.log {
        file "/var/log/query.log";
        // Set the severity to dynamic to see all the debug messages.
        severity dynamic;
    };

    category queries { query.log; };
};


dlz "Mysql zone" {
   database "mysql
   {host=172.16.254.100 port=3306 dbname=dyn_server_db user=db_user pass=db_password}
   {SELECT zone FROM dyn_dns_records WHERE zone = '$zone$'}
   {SELECT ttl, type, mx_priority, IF(type = 'TXT', CONCAT('\"',data,'\"'), data) AS data
    FROM dyn_dns_records
    WHERE zone = '$zone$' AND host = '$record$' AND type <> 'SOA' AND type <> 'NS'}
   {SELECT ttl, type, data, primary_ns, resp_person, serial, refresh, retry, expire, minimum
    FROM dyn_dns_records
    WHERE zone = '$zone$' AND (type = 'SOA' OR type='NS')}
   {SELECT ttl, type, host, mx_priority, IF(type = 'TXT', CONCAT('\"',data,'\"'), data) AS data, resp_person, serial, refresh, retry, expire, minimum
    FROM dyn_dns_records
    WHERE zone = '$zone$' AND type <> 'SOA' AND type <> 'NS'}
   {SELECT zone FROM xfr_table where zone='$zone$' AND client = '$client$'}";
};
```